# TCL global variable vs double colon variable

Tags: tcl

In TCL what is the difference between the code:

```
global MyVar
set MyVar 5
```

and the code

```
set ::MyVar 5
```

?
As far as I can understand ::MyVar means that MyVar would be a global variable. So what is the difference?

Comment: From a coder's point of view, no difference at all. How deep into the interpreter/bytecodes do you want to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is in a procedure, there's no functional difference to what variable gets set or what value gets put in it. (`global` has no effect outside of procedures, and other things with local variable tables such as lambdas and methods.)

Where there is an actual difference is in exactly how things are done. In particular, `global` sets things up once so that future unqualified variable accesses are fast, whereas using the qualified form *always* does a full lookup (which may involve multiple hash table accesses). The effect is such that while a single read or write is quicker with fully qualified form, multiple accesses are always quicker if done with `global` (and the effect becomes a bit stronger with multiple variables in the `global` call, as some of the costs are amortisable).

But don't take my word for it. Make some sample procedures and test for yourself with `time`, perhaps like this:

```
proc write1 {} {
    global MyVar
    set MyVar 5
    return
}
proc write2 {} {
    global MyVar
    set MyVar 5
    set MyVar 5
    return
}
proc write3 {} {
    global MyVar MyOtherVar
    set MyVar 5
    set MyOtherVar 5
    return
}
proc write4 {} {
    global MyVar MyOtherVar
    set MyVar 5
    set MyOtherVar 5
    set MyVar 5
    set MyOtherVar 5
    return
}
proc write5 {} {
    set ::MyVar 5
    return
}
proc write6 {} {
    set ::MyVar 5
    set ::MyVar 5
    return
}
proc write7 {} {
    set ::MyVar 5
    set ::MyOtherVar 5
    return
}
proc write8 {} {
    set ::MyVar 5
    set ::MyOtherVar 5
    set ::MyVar 5
    set ::MyOtherVar 5
    return
}

foreach cmd {write1 write2 write3 write4 write5 write6 write7 write8} {
    # Execute once to ensure everything is internally optimised
    $cmd
    # Now the timing run
    puts "$cmd : [time { $cmd } 100000]"
}
```

On my laptop (quite a few years old now) running Tcl 8.6.9, I get this:

```
write1 : 0.62610808 microseconds per iteration
write2 : 0.63969525 microseconds per iteration
write3 : 0.73437284 microseconds per iteration
write4 : 0.7519245699999999 microseconds per iteration
write5 : 0.62230006 microseconds per iteration
write6 : 0.8437912799999999 microseconds per iteration
write7 : 0.8246234299999999 microseconds per iteration
write8 : 1.2297289900000001 microseconds per iteration
```

As you can see (and confirm for yourself on your own hardware), `write1` is slower than `write5`, but for each of the other pairs, using `global` is a performance win. (I'm a little surprised that `write3` beats `write7`, but the figures don't lie.)

Comment: You might also see the difference in traces, and `info frame` can definitely see the difference too though that's really just a debugging tool.